# how to remove the enter key functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using a form and i have to use button and type is submit
when i pressed enter key the form submit, so i want to remove the functionality of enter key.

```
<input name="bb" id="bb" type="text" onKeyUp="Javascript: if(event.keycode==13) dont_submit(key); else show_error(this.value, event.keycode, this.id)";>


<script type="text/javascript">
function dont_submit(key)
{
    if(key)
    {
    return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

i also try this but not worked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function dont_submit(key)
{

    if(key == 13)
    {
    return false;
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Don't use `Javascript:` in event handlers! Where do people learn this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#bb').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wPecM/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
  if(e.which == 13) 
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't put a submit button but rather plain button with JS to submit the form:

```
<input type="button" class="SubmitButton" value="Submit" onclick="this.form.submit();" />
```

If you're concerned about visitors without JavaScript, use such code:

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        .SubmitButton { display: none; }
    </style>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').keypress(function () { 

      if(e.which == 13) {

        return false;
      }
});
```